# Tournament Management model

Tags: python, django

I'm creating tournament management web-app using [wagtail](https://wagtail.io/) and after searching for different solutions on the Internet came to the following:

```
YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(1999, (datetime.now().year+1)):
    YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))

class Staff(models.Model):
    """
    Each team has staff like: Coach, Assistant etc
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=POSITIONS)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('surname', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('position'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name, self.surname)

class Player(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=POSITIONS_SP)
    year_of_birth = models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.now().year)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('number'),
        FieldPanel('name', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('surname', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('position'),
        FieldPanel('year_of_birth'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name, self.surname)

class PlayerRelatedModel(models.Model):
    """
    Using ParentalKey allows me to add players dynamically.
    """
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    in_team = models.DateField()
    page = ParentalKey('PlayerContract',
        related_name='spieler_in_team')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('player', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('in_team', classname="col6")
    ]

class PlayerContract(ClusterableModel):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    team = models.ForeignKey('TeamRooster')
    in_team = models.DateField()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('team'),
        InlinePanel(
            'player_in_team', label="Add player",
            panels=None
        )
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} in {} seit {}".format(self.player, self.team, self.jahr)

class StaffContract(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    team = models.ForeignKey('TeamRooster')
    in_team = models.DateField()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('player'),
        FieldPanel('team'),
        FieldPanel('in_team'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} in {} seit {}".format(self.player, self.team, self.in_team)

class TeamRooster(Page):
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through=PlayerContract, blank=True)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField(Staff, through=StaffContract, blank=True)

    parent_page_types = ['Teams']

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('staff'),
        FieldPanel('player')
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Teams(Page):
    introduction = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the page',
        blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
    ]

    # Can only have TeamRooster children
    subpage_types = ['TeamRooster']

    # Returns a queryset of TeamRooster objects that are live, that are direct
    # descendants of this index page with most recent first
    def get_teams(self):
        return TeamRooster.objects.live().descendant_of(
            self).order_by('-first_published_at')

    # Allows child objects (e.g. TeamRooster objects) to be accessible via the
    # template. We use this on the HomePage to display child items of featured
    # content
    def children(self):
        return self.get_children().specific().live()

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(Teams, self).get_context(request)
        context['teams'] = TeamRooster.objects.descendant_of(
            self).live().order_by(
            '-date_published')
        return context
```

## Adding Players to team

[image]

I have very little experience in programming I will be happy with any corrections.

And please can someone add tag `wagtail` to this question?

Comment: did you write this code yourself, your phrasing suggests that you found this solution as opposed to writing this solution after researching.

Comment: @Malachi No, basically I took most of the code from other examples. In this code, everything is very simple, but it is not entirely correct. I'll update this code later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are few thoughts how the code could be slightly refactored.

The calculation of `YEAR_CHOICES` is little bit ugly. You could do it more elegant with a list comprehension:

```
from datetime import datetime

YEARS = [(year, year) for year in range(1999, datetime.now().year+1)]
```

Notice that I changed also some variable names. Naming is a very important skill.

It is much easier to understand `(year, year) for year in range(...)` instead of `for r in range(...)`. What does `r` stand for? The variable names should have some meaning.

You have another constant `POSITIONS`, which is not revealed in your question. You should be consistent and keep the same name convention throughout your project.

You could suffix all your choice constants with `_CHOICES`, like:

- YEAR_CHOICES
- POSITION_CHOICES

where the suffix would clutter the code and be redundant, or keep the names succinct, like:

- YEARS
- POSITIONS

If you have more choice constants, you could eventually put them in their own file. That's a matter of taste and depends on the size of your project. Personally if I have to use choices more frequently in my models, I create an extra file `choices.py` or `constants.py` and put all choices there. Then you can import them in the `models.py`:

```
from . import choices
```

and use them like this:

```
position = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=choices.POSITIONS)
```

Here we have another issue. Why is `max_length=128`? When you use choices, you would like to store a short string in the database and resolve it in the application. An example would be:

```
(
    ('FW', 'Forward'),
    ('LB', 'Left Back'),
    ('MF', 'Midfielder'),
)
```

Then you could set `max_length=2` and keep your database more performant.

Further you mix the coding style in the `ForeignKey` fields. Keep this:

```
team = models.ForeignKey('TeamRooster')
```

and adjust this:

```
player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

to:

```
player = models.ForeignKey('Player')
```

If you want to upgrade to Django 2, you'll have to pass `on_delete` to this field. Make your code future-proof and do that now. Even though it is not a mandatory argument, it is highly recommended to specify `related_name`. Here is an example:

```
player = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contracts')
```

Enclose in quotes the `through` arguments in the M2M fields, too:

```
player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='PlayerContract', blank=True)
```

Without knowing your user-story I can't provide further tips about the business logic of your app.

Comment: Thank you, ill use youre corrections in my code, as I sain in the comments this code is not enought correct, Im too busy at the moment maybe later ill update it.